# How to add Header to GridView in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, dart-pub

Hi i want to create a GridView.builder with crossAxisCount: 2 and scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal and each set of GridView needed an header please check the image

[Need to build something link this but](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Udlj.png)

Comment: Share your code and what you've attempted to do. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what do you mean by each set of gridview?

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya can you pls check the link.

Comment: @JoãoSoares im trying to create something just looks like image in the url. can you help me

Comment: @Thobio If you want help, you can start by checking the link I sent you and following the question guidelines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build using gridView.builder and Row widget in following way.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Demo"),
      ),
      body: Container(
          child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text("Top"),
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: GridView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemCount: 10,
                    gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 2),
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Text(index.toString());
                    },
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Text("Trending"),
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: GridView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemCount: 10,
                    gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 2),
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Text(index.toString());
                    },
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, the widget that are in the column ("Top","Trending") will be dynamic widget may increasing or decrease  depend on dynamic data eg : ("Top","Trending","Top Search" ....)  please help ....

Comment: I don't know any more context, so i can't help you that way. You can dynamically change value using variable.